# intellij idea 13.1.4 update scala plugin to v0.41 cause permission denied

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

After I update the scala plugin to v0.41 of intellij idea 13.1.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, I get following error when open a sbt project:

```
Error:Cannot run program "/home/abc/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51" (in directory "/home/abc/workspace/myproject"): error=13, Permission denied error=13, Permission denied
```

If I reinstall scala plugin with a lower version, everything works fine. Is it a bug or more configuration need to be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> Settings -> IDE Settings -> SBT

change the JVM from "Custom" to "Default".

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7481